# Python How to search substring with special symbols ? and * (RexExp like)

Tags: python, regex, glob

I should filtering string array by include substring and two recognizable character patterns for  `?` and `*`.

`?` - one any symbol

`*` - any amount of any symbols

With an example of data `['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']` it should work as:

```
'?b' -> ['baab', 'abbb']
'?a' -> ['baab']
'c?' -> []
'b??b' -> ['baab']
'???' -> ['baab', 'abbb']
'b*b' -> ['baab', 'abbb']
'***' -> ['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']
```

I can't use `in` operator for it.
What the most easy way to solve it? Perhaps it should be RegExp (But I'm not sure) or something else.

Comment: I would say `***` should throw an error. There is no point to match an infinite amount of chars a specified number of times. Or, these should be reduced to just 1 `*` then.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I think you absolutely right but I'm not a task maker for this case.

Comment: Ok, found one: `import fnmatch` and then `fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format(your_pattern))`. See https://ideone.com/iR8xKC

Answer (score 0):

A regex way is to 1) shrink all consecutive `*`s, 2) `re.escape` the parts between `?` and `*` and 3) replace each `*` with `.*` and `?` with `.` while compiling the regex with the `re.DOTALL` modifier:

```
import re

def repl(m):
    res = "{}{}".format(re.escape(m.group(1)), m.group(2).replace("*", ".*").replace("?", "."))
    if m.group(3):
        res += re.escape(m.group(3))
    return res

def glob_to_regex(glob):
    glob = re.sub(r'\*{2,}', '*', glob)
    return '(?s)' + re.sub(r'([^?*]*)([*?]+)([^?*]+$)?', repl , glob)

l = ['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA', 'abb.']
print([x for x in l if re.search(glob_to_regex('?b*b'), x)])
print([x for x in l if re.search(glob_to_regex('?b*.'), x)])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dIM1uy).

Here, a pattern like `?b***` will be translated to a `(?s).b.*` pattern that means:

- `(?s)` - an inline `re.DOTALL` modifier that makes `.` match line breaks, too
- `.` - any 1 char
- `b` - a `b` char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible.

**If you need to support any *glob* pattern** you need the [`fnmatch.filter(names, pattern)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) method that accepts a *glob* pattern (that is what your `?` and `*` are here, wildcards).

The unique issue here is that `fnmatch` globs must match the whole input while your patterns are unanchored.

Thus you need to wrap your patterns with `*`s:

```
import fnmatch
l = ['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('?b')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('?a')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('c?')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('b??b')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('???')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('b*b')))
print(fnmatch.filter(l, '*{}*'.format('***')))
```

Output:

```
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab']
[]
['baab']
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iR8xKC).

Comment: `fnmatch` also does character classes and OS-dependent case normalization, though. This question sounds more like homework than straight shell globbing, so character classes and case normalization are probably unwanted.

Comment: @user2357112 See the top of the updated answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, no, because now there's even more probably-unwanted functionality, like *regex* character classes and groups and backslash escapes and all that. (Also, the input pattern might contain `.` characters that should have been matched literally.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions:
For any character, use one point -
for any amount of any characters, use one point followed by a star -
for 0 or 1 character, use one point followed by an interrogation mark.

```
import re
define shortlist (pattern, list):
    return [s for s in list if re.search(pattern, s)]

mylist = ['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']
l = shortlist('.b', mylist)  # l = ['baab', 'abbb']
l = shortlist('.a', mylist)  # l = ['baab']
l = shortlist('b..b', mylist)  # l = ['baab']
l = shortlist('b.*b', mylist)  # l = ['baab', 'abbb']
l = shortlist('.{3}', mylist) # l = ['baab', 'abbb']
```

Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for the complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

you could fix the pattern by replacing '?' with `.` and `*` with `.*?` in  `recognizable character patterns` and return any `substring` that contains at least only one match (`re.search`):

```
import re

example = ['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']

def filter_by_pattern(elements, pattern):
    # convert `?` and `*` flags
    pattern = pattern.replace('?', '.').replace('*', '.*?')
    # you could make this a generator instead of list if you like
    return [substring for substring in elements if re.search(pattern, substring)]

print(filter_by_pattern(example , '?b'))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , '?a'))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , 'c?'))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , 'b??b'))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , '???' ))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , 'b*b' ))
print(filter_by_pattern(example , '***' ))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab']
[]
['baab']
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab', 'abbb']
['baab', 'abbb', 'fc', 'AA']
```